# A three digit number is 12 times larger than the sum of its digits. What is that number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I set up an equation $100a+10b+c=12(a+b+c)$, and from there I don't know what to do.

Comment: Well, $a$ can't be very big.... In fact, it's easy to see that $12(a + b + c) \le 12 \cdot 27 = 324$. So that's already extremely restrictive.

Comment: $88a = 2b+11c$. So $c$ must be even. $2b+11c\leq 11\cdot 8+18=106$, so $a=1$.

Comment: Why is it that problem statement question showing no effort, when posted under the elementary-number-theory get more upvotes than do other similarly poor questions posted under most other tags, and far more elementary answers from users who pretend to not notice a bare PSQ statement?

Comment: Using modulo $11$ or considering divisibility by $11$ is quicker than using $2$ - see Omar Khayyam's answer below.

Comment: @amWhy I don't agree that this qualifies as a bare PSQ - after all, the asker *has* set up an equation for it.

Comment: "Times as much as", please. "Times larger than" comes from innumerate journalists who get confused when trying to distinguish a multiple from a proportional increment..

Answer (score 2):

If the number is exactly $12$ times the sum of its digits, then as you mentioned
$$100a+10b+c=12a+12b+12c.$$
Now we have
$$88a-11c=11(8a-c)=2b $$
thus $11$ devides $2b$ whivh implies $b=0$. This implies that $8a=c$, or $a=1$ and $c=8$, so your number is $108$.

Answer (score 2):

From your equation, we get $88a=2b+11c$. Since $b,c\leq 9$, this means that $88a\leq 13\cdot 9=117$ so $a=1$.

Now you need $88=2b+11c$. With $b<10$ this means that $88\leq 20+11c$ or $c>6$. We also have $c\leq 8$. But we see that $c$ must be even, so $c=8$ and $b=0$.

Comment: Or, from 88=2b+11c , we see that 11 divides 2b=88-11c so 11 divides b so b=0.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to narrow things down.

First, there are only three choices for $a$. The number can't be larger than $999$, so $a$ can't be larger than $3$ ($27\times 9 =324$).

Second, the number is divisible by $12$.

Can you take it from here?